# Помогите решить ошибку на Django

Tags: django

Когда,я запускаю сервер на Django
Вылезает эта ошибка:PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(**file**)
                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код покажете полностью? Желательно с полным `traceback`'ом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предыдущей строчке не хватает закрывающей скобки.

Comment: а где точно,можете подсказать пожалуйста,а то я новичок в django

Comment: @Ovsanka 16 строка. Там 3 открывающие скобки и лишь 2 закрывающие.

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: @Ovsanka Если этот ответ Вам помог, то Вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на зелёную галочку слева.